# Is it possible to assign SetupIconFile from .exe file?

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup has a `SetupIconFile` directive to specify an .ico file that the installer binary itself will get. But I don't want to specify my app's .ico file which is buried deep down in the app's resources. The installer already has access to the application binary, can't the icon be extracted from there?

This works:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\App.exe
```

But this doesn't:

```
SetupIconFile=binaries\App.exe
```

> Resource update error: Icon file is invalid.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The `SetupIconFile` is loaded by the Inno Setup compiler. It supports the `.ico` files only.

The `UninstallDisplayIcon` is loaded by Windows (Control Panel). Inno Setup installer only stores the value of the `UninstallDisplayIcon` to the installed program's uninstall entry (value `DisplayIcon`). Windows supports other formats, like `.exe` and `.dll`, in addition to `.ico`.